# Spark Load only specific set of files

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following list of files generated:

```
file_20231603_134035_000000.xml,
file_20231603_073340_000003.xml,
file_20231503_073340_000009.xml,
file_20231503_073340_000015.xml,
file_20231503_073340_000021.xml,
file_20231503_072807_000000.xml,
file_20231403_073340_000004.xml,
file_20231303_073340_000010.xml,
file_20231303_073340_000016.xml,
file_20231403_073340_000022.xml
```

I would like to load only yesterday and today set of files using globbing. I tried like so, but it didnt work as expected.

```
val dafo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0)
val currentDate = dafo.format(calendar.getTime)
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
val previousDate = dafo.format(calendar.getTime)

sparkSession.read
          .format("xml")
          .option("rootTag", "foo")
          .option("rowTag", "bar")
          .load(s"file_(${previousDate}|${currentDate})*.xml")
```

I am not sure if this regex works as expected `s"file_(${previousDate}|${currentDate})*.xml"`
What should be the right way of specificying such regex?

Answer (score 0):

The `load` method expects the exact path (or paths) of the files to load. It does not support any form of regex or glob. [Link to API Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#load(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

So... you just have to provide the list of paths.

```scala
val allPaths = List(...)

val regex = "...".r

val matchingPaths = allPaths.filter(p => regex.matches(p))

val df = 
sparkSession.read
  .format("xml")
  .option("rootTag", "foo")
  .option("rowTag", "bar")
  .load(matchingPaths: _*)
```

Comment: The problem with the above approach in my case is that the directory over which I need to filter for currentDate and previousDate is incrementally increasing everyday. I believe with every run on the above snippet would cause performance problems.